# Can't bind or listen to Memgraphs sockets

Tags: memgraphdb

It makes no difference if I try to bind or listen to Memgraph I get the error. Depengin on the thing that I'm trying to do I get either: `Cannot bind to socket on endpoint {}` or `Cannot listen on socket endpoint {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Memgraph uses port `7687`. It seems that some other application or process is using that port and is preventing you from connecting to the socket.

Another reason could be starting of another Memgraph instance on the same port.